# OPNsense routes traffic to its own IP into IPsec VPN

Tags: routing, ipsec, pfsense

I have a OPNsense device with an IPsec VPN to a remote site, which works fine. All traffic from the LAN should go through the VPN, so I configured the Phase 2 like this:

- Local Subnet: LAN network
- Remote Subnet: 0.0.0.0/0

All traffic from my LAN now goes into the tunnel. However, this means that even IP packets to the firewall itself are routed through the VPN. I can see them on the remote gateway, where they are dropped (obviously). As a consequence, I cannot reach the OPNsense web UI from my LAN interface anymore. Other interfaces keep working as expected.

**How can I prevent OPNsense from sending traffic that is destined directly to its own interfaces into the VPN tunnel?**

My first idea was to add a static route, but I am unsure if that would be possible, as there is no next hop.

Please note that this is not a question about regaining access to the management UI, I know how to do that. What I want to do is allow access from the LAN, while other LAN traffic is sent into the tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with the static route idea. Routes are prioritized based on how specific they are.

0.0.0.0/0 is the most generic and should always be evaluated last.

I would suggest setting a route that matches the remote network instead for just `0.0.0.0/0`. Something like `10.2.0.0/16` or whatever matches your networks. You can also create one for the local network like `10.1.0.0/16` (or whatever) to make sure it can connect to local devices.

Comment: What would be the next hop for the local network? It is directly connected to the device, so there is no other router on the LAN.